# autoit3 - trigger context menu to open on button click/press

Tags: autoit

I am working on a project, in which I decided I should have history of previously searched stuff (since it's an app with which you can search stuff), so I have been thinking that I could just create the context menu or regular menu, that I could somehow force to activate on a button click or by using accelerators.

Now, I haven't been able to figure out how to make that work.

First I tried the `GuiCtrlSetState()` function, which didn't seem to work (I tried show and focus), then I tried accelerators and they didn't do anything.

- So I'm wondering is there any way I can make the context menu or regular menu pop up on button press/click or key press (with accelerators)?

So what I'm basically trying to do is some sort of a pop-up, you click on a button or press a key to trigger the context menu or regular menu to open.

I know I could be old school and use a new GUI or just a combo box for the history or anything but I kinda want this, if there's any way to do so.

- Any help, or an alternative way of doing the same thing appreciated.
- Here's the testing code in which I was trying to make the test button trigger and activate the context menu, and I have tried the same with the regular
  menu:

```
#NoTrayIcon
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

GUICreate("test123")
$but = guictrlcreatebutton("test", -1, -1, -1)
$xt  = GUICtrlCreateContextMenu("test context menu")
       GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("test1", $xt)
       GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("test2", $xt)
GUISetState(@SW_MAXIMIZE)

While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()

    If $msg = $but Then
        GUICtrlSetState($xt, $GUI_FOCUS)
    EndIf

    Sleep(5)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the help file under GUICtrlCreateContextMenu:

```
; right click on gui to bring up context Menu.
; right click on the "ok" button to bring up a controll specific context menu.

#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    GUICreate("My GUI Context Menu", 300, 200)

    Local $idContextmenu = GUICtrlCreateContextMenu()

    Local $idNewsubmenu = GUICtrlCreateMenu("new", $idContextmenu)
    Local $idNewsubmenuText = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("text", $idNewsubmenu)

    Local $idButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("OK", 100, 100, 70, 20)
    Local $idButtoncontext = GUICtrlCreateContextMenu($idButton)
    Local $idMenuAbout = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("About button", $idButtoncontext)

    Local $idMenuOpen = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("Open", $idContextmenu)
    Local $idMenuSave = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("Save", $idContextmenu)
    GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("", $idContextmenu) ; separator

    Local $idMenuInfo = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("Info", $idContextmenu)

    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    ; Loop until the user exits.
    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Button Clicked", 'OK')
            Case $idMenuAbout
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Menu Selected", 'About')
            Case $idMenuOpen
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Menu Selected", 'Open')
            Case $idMenuSave
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Menu Selected", 'Save')
            Case $idMenuInfo
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Menu Selected", 'Info')
            Case $idNewsubmenuText
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "SubMenu Selected", 'Text')
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
    GUIDelete()
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is make the context menu somehow appear with left click or a key press on the button. Currently, I use function ControlClick to do that

Comment: On a button that is not your own GUI creation?  So you really don't want a contextmenu, because a contextmenu is for the non-primary mouse throughout all languages I've ever used.  What you want is a [custom pop-up gui solution](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/103008-popup-menu-udf/)?

Comment: Yes, that's waht I've been looking for. thanks lots.